# SQL Server Current_Timestamp Format

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm learning SQL Server and have an update statement where the current date and time are inserted as follows:

```
UPDATE data_table 
SET Date_Time_Cx = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When it is populated in the DB, it appears `"Feb 22 2018 5:07PM"`. How do I get to populate with the format `"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"`? I looked through the SQL Server documents and lots of posts and it seems like it should be populating in the desired way. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: in sql regardless of the format a datetime is a datetime... but if you are after of the presentation use `convert` with formatting `(100,103...)`

Comment: The format of dates and times are due to the application you are using to look at it.  The data is the proper type.  There is no cause for concern.  If you are using Management Studio, I'm not sure, but, it might be picking up your Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: Dan, it's strange because I am looking at it through Management Studio and the other populated rows in the field are in the correct format from when I hard coded them (ie '2018-02-22 10:53:10') into the DB. It's only when I run my WPF app and use the above statement that I get the "Feb 22 ...." value. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Then change the type of `date_time_cx`:

```
alter table data_table alter column date_time_cx datetime2;
```

Then it should go into the database using the proper types. You can format the value as you wish afterwards.

Comment: Ok. So it's some kind of conversion when it's populated as a nvarchar that's causing the issue?

Comment: @Progolfer79 . . . It may be converting the current timestamp to a string, based on server configurations.  That could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this has to do with C#, but here's a solution for you using base SQL.

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121)
```

You can find all kinds of different date and time formats from the link below.

https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/